# Bitcoind Cannot assign requested address

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, regtest

I'm trying to run a regtest bitcoind node but I'm always receiving the following error

> connect() to [2a05:d01c:a35:2902:6e18:7290:ff27:e9aa]:18444 failed:
>   Cannot assign requested address (99)

My config:

```
bitcoind -printtoconsole -regtest=1 -rpcallowip=::/0 -rpcauth="...."
```

I'm running the node with through docker with the following image https://hub.docker.com/r/ruimarinho/bitcoin-core/

Thanks by advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check that your system support IpV6.
Run this:

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "IPv6 supported" || echo "IPv6 not supported"
```

Then make sure to bind to `::ffff:0.0.0.0`